# SELECT DISTINCT with INNER JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql

Hello All,

This sound very simple but I'm having a problem here.

There are tables:

```
table_A
TA_id | TA_user | TA_hour | TA_date
```

and

```
table_B
TB_id | TB_name | TB_adress
```

Here is the query:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT 
                    DISTINCT TA_user 
                    FROM table_A 
                    INNER JOIN table_B ON table_B.id = table_A.TA_user 
                    WHERE TA_date LIKE '%$vardate%' 
                    ORDER BY TA_user ASC ");
```

When I run the While loop in the array the TB_name that shuld print cause the inter join dosen't work.

Any ideas ?

Comment: You're not selecting a `TB_name`, you know that, right?

Comment: Yes I know but if I don't use the DISTINCT as I done before I can call any column from the inner joined table that works...

Comment: I guess you're question is unclear.  You can't print anything from `TB_name` unless you select it...

Comment: If I run '$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table_A INNER JOIN table_B ON table_B.id = table_A.TA_user WHERE TA_date LIKE '%$vardate%' ORDER BY TA_user ASC ");' works but repeat all the records... no distinct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to me that you have multiple table A records for a given table B entity, is that right?

By the way, your column names are horrible...table_B.id = table_A.TA_user???? how is someone examining your database supposed to know that relationship exists? But that's beside the point.

Anyway, I guess that you're trying to return the table B entities that have records in table_A for a given date?

If so, distinct should work for you. I'd probably use group by instead because it's generally faster. But this should do what you want, if I understand you correctly.

```
SELECT DISTINCT table_B.TB_name
    FROM table_A 
        INNER JOIN table_B
            ON table_B.TB_id = table_A.TA_user
    WHERE TA_date LIKE '%$vardate%'
    ORDER BY TA_user ASC;
```

And, as @Gordon Linoff says above, the LIKE with a date field is suspicious. His idea there seems appropriate to me.

Comment: True about the suspicious use of LIKE, always learning sometihing more. Your soluction works just fine. When we need to DISTINCT should be in the 2nd table not in the 1st. Very good, thks a lot.

Comment: no DISTINCT doesn't go with a table, but with the whole query. The reason you need a DISTINCT here is that there are multiple A record for each B, and you only want to see the B's. The query returns a row for every record that matches, whether you display it or not. So, you get a row for every match between A & B. If you wanted both A & B data, you wouldn't need DISTINCT.

Answer (score 0):

First, don't use deprecated interfaces like "mysql_".  Use mysqli or PDO.  But, focusing on your query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TA_user
FROM table_A INNER JOIN
     table_B
     ON table_B.id = table_A.TA_user
WHERE TA_date LIKE '%$vardate%'
ORDER BY TA_user ASC;
```

One possibility is that the join key is not correct.  Assuming it is, the other big issue is using `like` with a date.  It is not clear exactly what you want, but I am guessing that it is something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TA_user
FROM table_A INNER JOIN
     table_B
     ON table_B.id = table_A.TA_user
WHERE TA_date = date('$vardate')
ORDER BY TA_user ASC;
```

You will want `$vardate` to be in the format of "YYYY-MM-DD" to ensure proper conversion.  Or, better yet, make it a parameter instead of an embedded constant.

Comment: Tahnks for your time, but the WHERE works fine if I don't use DISTINCT in the same query..... that is not the problem :(

Answer (score 0):

I reach the deal : `$sql = mysql_query("SELECT 
                    * FROM table_A 
                    INNER JOIN table_B ON table_B.id = table_A.TA_user 
                    WHERE TA_date LIKE '%$vardate%' 
                    GROUP BY TA_user ");`

Comment: True, but print the result I need, the @Cris answer woks fine too with DISITNCT.